# How do I import a CSV with a large header in KDB?

Tags: kdb

This is how we import normally a CSV (with 5 string columns) to a table.

```
table: ("SSSSS" ;enlist ",") 0: `input.csv
```

However, I have a CSV file with 255 columns. Do I need to type 255 S's to have them imported this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"S" would import as a symbol type.

For string use * and you can also combine with take e.g.

```
table: (255#"*" ;enlist ",") 0: `input.csv
```

http://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#take